# error in manifest file

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have encountered this issue many times although i have already re-written the codes. I've have done a clean up several times. However, there's error still in my xml manifest.

Apparently there's errors on applying the permission to send and receive SMS. Will someone be able to guide me? I'm just a beginner in coding out for SMS in eclipse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sms"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></</uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.sms.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></</uses-permission>
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Notice the closing brackets

Comment: I have done that too. its stated that "The <uses-permission> element must be a direct child of the <manifest> root element"

Comment: After i did the clean up, an error appears stating that Element type "uses-adk" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Answer (score 1):

Remove below line, its not required

```
</</uses-permission>
```

`/>` depicts a closing tag.

Add `/>` instead `>` ,above line does not mean anything.

Updated manifest

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sms.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

You have missed **closing tag** for **uses-sdk**

Comment: I have removed that too but error kinda remains there. Is there missing in the xml file? i did a proper closing and yet there's an error.

Comment: Thank you! I just used your updated manifest. I realised that you did the closing for the <uses-sdk which i failed to. There aren't any errors now. Thank you very much!